# How to identify NOT used controllers, factories, directives

Tags: angularjs

I have huge angularjs app, with lots of controllers,factories and directives. I would like to find out if any of the component (controllers,factories and directives) NOT in use delete whole js. E.g. If controller "aboutController" is NOT used anywhere I want to delete it. Same way for factories and directives.

I have tried chrome's extension- JavaScript Tracker. I am also trying to use gulp-unused but it is providing NOT used code and I need NOT used js.